# How do I make a simple web app with log-in?

Tags: java, android, web-applications

I have been doing android programming for a while now but only as a hobby. I know the basics of java, and can say I have a solid understanding of PHP and MySQL (I once followed a tutorial that showed how to create a very basic content management system). I've been wanting to expand my knowledge beyond the simple android apps I've made and recently had an idea for an android app. In this app, the user would create a Username and password the first time it is ran. From then, the user can fill out a form. From what i know so far, the valuesof this form can be stored in a MySQL database. So basically every user needs to have their own set of variables stored (which are not a lot). As I been looking around, i think there are many ways to create a web app, and there are different frameworks for doing so. I read I can create a web app with log-in, using ASP.NET. Can this be done using java? I just need some general guidance. I want to make the web app standalone, and then focus on creating an app for android that uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think good platform for your kind of case is to use Google App Engine (GAE). It provides platform to do your web-service with Java (or python if you prefer). It is also free for low amounts of traffic (like your service) and they have really good tools to manage the site (check the database entries, usage statistics, etc.).

Google has written a good set of tutorials to build webservice with Java in GAE:

http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/

AppEngine documentation main page:

http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/appengine/

Signup here:

https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: Thanks, I had come across this but wasn't sure it would provide everything I needed, but will now dive into learning it because of your answer

Comment: I followed the First tutorial, but can't run or debug. I get this
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Guestbook".
com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException when i click debug as
And this when i click run as:
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Guestbook".
org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel
I'm using Eclipse Indigo. Any ideas?

Comment: solved. The problem to this was that ADT doesnt work well with App Engine plugin.

Comment: @FranciscoBárcena I use them in different Eclipse instance so I haven't experienced this. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at [JavaServer Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages).